# Cannot find file error

Tags: python, windows, file

Small python script to split a large data file into many smaller files (some 100,000 or so) - basically map tiling.

Anyway, after a long time (20+hrs) of running the script it dies with:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ......
```

Now this strikes me as odd as NONE of the files existed before the script runs - and f.close() is called after every file has been written, so FD limits don't seem to be responsible... (and plenty of disk space)

The other odd thing was that all the files it had already created/written (about 55,000) were deleted along with the containing directory when the script died.

I used the multiprocessing module to create a process for each CPU core, and all 4 spat out the same message on dying - but with a file in the section of data they were processing (perhaps this is relevant?)

I can hopefully work around this, but am just curious as to why this might have occured ??

*Edit: For more context, the script is splitting the GSHHS geo data into small 'tiles'. Now, I have succesfully done this for the lower resolution sections of the DB, into files containing larger areas of the globe - it fell over when trying to split the hi resolution data into 1x1° tiles*

Comment: Perhaps the filename/path will give you a better clue

Comment: All files were put in the same path. filename generated by which data it contained, like '1_2.xml' - and like I said, it failed on 4 different files simultaneously... The numeric values are between 0-360 and 0-180 (covering the globe @ 1°x1°)

Comment: You say the directory was deleted; may be this actually was the cause of the error, i.e. somehow it was deleted, hence trying to create a file in it lead to an error for all processes.

Comment: Yes it could be - but the machine was not in use other that the script running, so I couldn't think of anything that may have deleted it.

Comment: Try printing the filename before you're call to open to detect which caused the error....OR catch the exception and print it in the exception code.

Comment: What happens if you try to split it sequentially into 4/5 files instead?

Comment: If you have lots of diskspace, use sysinternals procmon to monitor the execution and see what syscalls happen. I wouldn't rule out a Python bug/limitation on windows, it has a few surprising ones (especially with Python 2.x). Also watch out for shell extension (Tortoise SVN/Git, some Adobe stuff, Virus scanners), that might do silly things if you try some patterns of open/rename/delete.